# ¿Como puedo agregar un nombre(String) dentro de un array predefinido en java?

Tags: java, array, método

1. Cargar un arreglo con 3 nombres de frutas predefinidos

   String frutas[]={"manzana","naranja","melon"};

2.Agregar un nombre al listado por teclado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es posible agregar un elemento a un arreglo que ya está lleno. Si tienes un arreglo de 3 posiciones, no puedes modificarlo después. Puedes reemplazar el nombre de una posición por otro nombre pero, no agregar más. Se me ocurren dos opciones para resolver tu problema.

**Opción 1:** Crear un arreglo con una posición de más para guardar en la última el nombre de la fruta recibida por teclado.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Arreglo con 1 dimension más para el String solicitado
        String[] frutas = new String[4];
        frutas[0] = "manzana";
        frutas[1] = "naranja";
        frutas[2] = "melon";

        // Variable para guardar el nombre de la fruta ingresada
        String nuevaFruta;

        // Pedir el nombre de una fruta por teclado
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de una fruta: ");
        nuevaFruta = scanner.nextLine();

        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();

        // Guardar el nombre de la nueva fruta en la última posición del arreglo
        frutas[3] = nuevaFruta;

        // Imprimir arreglo
        for (String nombre : frutas) {
            System.out.println(nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

**Opción 2:** Usar `ArrayList`, su ventaja es que el numero de elementos que almacena, lo hace de forma dinámica, es decir, que no es necesario declarar su tamaño como pasa con los Arrays.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        // ArrayList de tipo String
        ArrayList<String> frutas = new ArrayList<>();

        // Arregar frutas al ArrayList
        frutas.add("manzana");
        frutas.add("naranja");
        frutas.add("melon");

        // Pedir el nombre de una fruta por teclado
        System.out.println("Ingrese el nombre de una fruta: ");

        // Guardar el nombre de la fruta en el ArrayList
        frutas.add(scanner.nextLine());

        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();

        // Imprimir arreglo
        for (String nombre : frutas) {
            System.out.println(nombre);
        }
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda bro

Answer (score 0):

Los arreglos en java no son redimensionables, por lo que no es posible agregar una posición más al arreglo `frutas`, puesto que su definición restringe su tamaño a 3 elementos.

Si los requerimientos de su aplicación indican que se debe permitir al usuario agregar elementos a la colección indefinidamente, le recomiendo que utilice una estructura de datos de tipo lista, por ejemplo `ArrayList`.